# Python thread dont start

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to make class that have function which will do something in background. I googled and looked at all exampled and I am still confused why my background thread is running all the time, it never stops...
What I want is that my background thread starts and after 3 seconds my main thread should change variable value and background thread should stop. Here is simplified example of my class:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class ThreadingExample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._stop = False
        self._thread = Thread(target=self.run())
        self._thread.daemon = True
        self._thread.start()

    def run(self):
        while self._stop == False:
            print("doing something")
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop_run(self):
        print("stop doing!")
        self._stop = True

example = ThreadingExample()
time.sleep(3)
example.stop_run()
print('Bye')
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self._stop = True` in your `stop_run` method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self._thread = Thread(target=self.run)
```

You have to **pass** the target (the function object) and **not execute** it, because the execution is an endless loop in the main thread and you never come back to have the chance to call `stop_run` to stop the execution.

Comment: wow, thank you very much! What a stupid mistake... I will mark this as answered. Thank you again!